# Send data over 3G when connected to WiFi on iOS

Tags: ios, wifi, 3g

I would like to send out data via 3G when my iPhone is connected to my ARDrone. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually possible since the connection is adhoc and apparently informs the iPhone that there is no internet through it, since I was piloting one and had MLB live streaming a game in the background.

Comment: Ah, I assumed you meant it was connected to the Internet via the wi-fi.  Good to know that the underlying mechanisms figured it out and used the 3G.  I've definitely been on super-slow public wi-fi and had to turn it off to get some data pushed/pulled.

Answer (score 2):

no, it's not.

[iPhone: Connecting to the Internet](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1695)

"When you use these interfaces, you do not have to choose whether to use the Wi-Fi or cell-based radios yourself." - [Networking & Internet Starting Point](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Networking_iPhone/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007301) - the implication being you don't have the choice, either.